# Change default value of a combo box

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, combobox

So I'm trying to make an App that creates an order based on menu choices.  The menu uses combo boxes and then I use the combo box choice to add the numbers for the total.  However, the default value of the combo boxes is blank, and I'd like it to be '0'.  How do I change the selected Index to 0 instead of minus one without overwriting the choice of the user.  My code:

```
Public Class addOrder

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim A = Convert.ToInt32(margQty.Text) * 9.5
    Dim B = Convert.ToInt32(hawQty.Text) * 10.5
    Dim C = Convert.ToInt32(pepQty.Text) * 10.5
    Dim D = Convert.ToInt32(pepDelQty.Text) * 11.5
    Dim E1 = Convert.ToInt32(pineQty.Text) * 0.5
    Dim F = Convert.ToInt32(hamQty.Text) * 0.5
    Dim G = Convert.ToInt32(cheQty.Text) * 1.0
    Dim H = Convert.ToInt32(exPepQty.Text) * 0.5
    Dim SubTot As Double = (A + B + C + D + E1 + F + G + H)
    Dim Tot As String = (SubTot) * 1.2

    MsgBox("The order sub total total is: £" + Str(SubTot) & vbCrLf & "The order total is £" + Tot)

  End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: You could set the listindex to 0 as part of you form load.

Comment: how do I manually load the form? because it's in Visual Studio the IDE loads it automatically and I don't know where to add the load code

Comment: he means the Form Load event

Comment: Add it to the form's load event procedure. If you double-click on the form in the IDE, it will take you into that procedure in the code-behind file.

Comment: Also I'd recommend adding the "Option Strict On" declaration at the top of the code window and avoid using untyped variables.

Comment: @GuruJosh Of course it is a type.  It's an object or a variant.. :)

Comment: It's good programming practice to type variables as tightly as possible. If variables A to H are only ever going to contain Doubles or Decimals then they should be typed accordingly. I would also avoid doing implicit type conversions such as the calculation on the Tot variable. Tot should be typed as a Double. You can always cast it to a string later if necessary.

Comment: I'll add that Keith is correct below. You need to set the combo box's SelectedIndex property to zero. The ListIndex property doesn't belong to the ComboBox class in VB.NET.

Comment: I also notice that you are doing currency calculations. In this case, you should type your variables as Decimal. Double doesn't have the required precision for currency calculations.

Answer (score 1):

During your Form Load event (double-click the form in the IDE), populate your combo box, then use this to set the default index:

e.g.:

```
Private Sub frmName_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Me.Load

'Load/call whatever you'd like for this particular form
'...

'Populate your combo box through a list or manually
'... 

'Set the default selected index:
If YourComboBox.Items.Count > 0
    YourComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0

End Sub
```

Comment: Make sure to check for the existence of at least one item in the combo box's Item collection with "If ComboBox1.Items.Count > 0 Then ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0".